# How to export form reference to another class for reusing?

Tags: vb.net, class

I have this code. I use this for moving window without windows bar.

```
' FUNCTIONS FOR WINDOW MOVEMENT    ------------------------------------------------------------------------

' Left mouse button pressed
Private Sub Login_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseDown
    If e.Button = sender.MouseButtons.Left Then
        ' Get the new position
        mouseOffset = New Point(-e.X, -e.Y)
        ' Set that left button is pressed
        isMouseDown = True
    End If
End Sub

' MouseMove used to check if mouse cursor is moving
Private Sub Login_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove
    If isMouseDown Then
        Dim mousePos As Point = Control.MousePosition
        ' Get the new form position
        mousePos.Offset(mouseOffset.X, mouseOffset.Y)
        Me.Location = mousePos
    End If
End Sub

' Left mouse button released, form should stop moving
Private Sub Login_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseUp
    If e.Button = sender.MouseButtons.Left Then
        isMouseDown = False
    End If
End Sub
```

How can I export this code to a external class for reusing in another form?

I have this question because I want to reuse it in each form in my app. I can't do it because when I pass Me.form as parameter, I get an error.

Comment: Create a MustInherit BaseForm-class that has all the shared code and inherit that.

Comment: `sender.MouseButtons.Left` this can´t even compile.

Comment: Putting this in a base class is the correct way since it appears to implement common behavior for a window without a titlebar.  But it must not be MustInherit or the derived form cannot be designed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Esko already mentioned in his comment, create a base form class which inherits from `Windows.Form` and define your mouse event handlers there:

```
Public MustInherit Class BaseForm
       Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

  Private mouseOffset As Point
  Private isMouseDown As Boolean

  Private Sub Login_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseDown
     ' ...
  End Sub

  ' MouseMove used to check if mouse cursor is moving
  Private Sub Login_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove
      '...
  End Sub

 ' Left mouse button released, form should stop moving
  Private Sub Login_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseUp
      '...
  End Sub
End Class
```

(Make sure that `BaseForm` is the only class in its own file).

In the `Designer.vb` file of your forms (e.g. Form1) change the inheritance from

`Partial Class Form1
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form`

to

`Partial Class Form1
    Inherits BaseForm`

Comment: Visual Studio throw [this error](http://i.imgur.com/zPPGVsy.png), however... it works...

Comment: Your Login class seems to have additional partical class definitions where the inheritance is already setup

Comment: I think that but I cannot find where I could change inherit at design time in visual studio 2015

Comment: It should be in the file `Login.Designer.vb`. If you can´t see it open the Solution Explorer -> Click on your **project** file -> In the small Solution Explorer item bar select `Show All Files` icon.

Comment: I did. Click on [this button](http://i.imgur.com/UDSSgg9.png), type "design" and select yorform.vb. Then, change "Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form" by "Inherits BaseForm" as you said. Thanks!!!

Comment: Exactly!! Sorry, I wrote when your comment hadn't been published.